# Pesquisa no banco de dados MySQL MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um `Search` que pesquisa pelo nome, mas queria que ele pesquisasse tanto pelo nome quanto pelo lugar no mesmo campo de pesquisa.

Segue a action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Search(FormCollection fc, string searchString)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                var clientes = db.Locals.Include(c => c.Cidades).Include(e => e.Cidades.Estado).Where(c => c.Nome.Contains(searchString)).OrderBy(o => o.Nome);
                return View("Index", clientes.ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

Nesse `var clientes` queria pesquisar além do nome, pesquisar a cidade, e trazer todos daquela cidade, eu acredito que seja no próprio `where`, mas não sei...

Esse é o HTML da pesquisa:

```
@*Código de pesquisa*@
using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Local", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="form-horizontal">
      @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-10">
         @* @Html.TextBox("SearchString")*@
         Pesquisar: <input type="text" name="SearchString" id="SearchString" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.Pesquisa" />
        <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(FormCollection fc, string searchString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    var clientes = db.Locals
               // Não precisa do include na Cidades, porque quando você inclui o Estado que está dentro da Cidades ele já traz Cidades!
               //.Include(l => l.Cidades)
               .Include(l => l.Cidades.Estado)
               .Where(l => 
                      l.Nome.Contains(searchString) ||
                      l.Cidades.Nome.Contains(searchString)) //Não sei o nome do campo, só um exemplo...
               .OrderBy(l => l.Nome);
    return View("Index", clientes.ToList());
}
```

Só adicionar um operador **||** (OR) na cláusula *where*

Inverti seu if para o código ficar mais legível. E você não precisa de ELSE porque no if já tem um return =D

Comment: Obrigado Cara, era para um projeto da Faculdade e já foi finalizado, mas será de grande utilidade pra mim futuramente, e quando testar, marco a resposta como aceita. Obrigado